# Android wait volley response to process next index inside for loop

Tags: android, for-loop, android-volley

```
    for(int t = 0; t<saveUnSavedReqList.size(); t++) {
        saveUnSavedReqInfo(param1,param2, new saveUnSavedReqInfoCallBack() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(boolean isSended) {
                                if(isSended) {
                                     unSendedsaveUnSavedReqList.add(saveUnSavedReqList.get(t));
                                }
                            }
                        });
   }
```

Is it possible to keep waiting to process next index by the time request response return?